# convert JSON array to space separated string

Tags: bash, json, jq

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
 "name" : "Allow",
 "source" : [ "*" ,"0.0.0.0"]
}
```

I need to parse this JSON so the array of strings inside JSON can convert to "space separated string". I later need to supply these variables to another function like this:

```
local file="file-name"
while read val; do
    local name
    local source

    name=$(jq --raw-output '.name' <<< ${val})
    source=$(jq --raw-output '.source' <<< ${val})
__test "${name}" "${source}" 
  done < <(cat ${file} | jq -rc '.[]')
```

So,I basically need to change source to a string and pass it, rather than a list of strings.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here (in particular, why you are using a shell loop to process the file line-by-line) - but `jq` has a built in function for joining elements of an array `jq -r '.source | join(" ")'` and also a built in TSV filter `jq -r '.source | @tsv'`

Comment: Basically, what I am asking here is that source should have "* 0.0.0.0" and not "*","0.0.0.0". It should be passed as one string

Comment: Please put your expected output from the example into your question. There's clearly some confusion over what you mean by "_space separated string_"

Comment: When asking a question like this one typically enter **A)** a usable input sample including various scenarios. **B)** A desired output sample (manually modified) **C)** What one have tried and where one are stuck. It is very important to specify clearly what the end-result should be - and add information to question by [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/655556/edit), not in comments.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the elements of an array may be converted to a single space-delimited string using `join(" ")` in `jq`.  In your case, the `.source` array may be converted into a space-delimited string using `.source | join(" ")`.

I'm assuming that your input document contains an array of objects of the type that you show in the question.

Instead of calling `jq` multiple times in each iteration, consider using `jq` to get the data into a form that is usable as a single stream:

```bsh
jq -r '.[] | [ .name, (.source | join(" ")) ] | @tsv' file.json |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r name source; do
    __test "$name" "$source"
done
```

This provides two tab-delimited fields to the loop.  The first field is simply the `.name` value from the JSON document, while the second field is a space-delimited string made by concatenating the elements from the `.source` array. The concatenation of array elements into a singe string is done with `join()` in `jq`, and the tab-delimited output is produced by providing `@tsv` with an array.

---

If you feel brave, you could even use

```bsh
eval "$( jq -r '.[] | [ "__test", .name, (.source | join(" ")) ] | @sh' file.json )"
```

This uses `jq` to actually create the shell commands that you aim to execute.  The calling shell then gets this *script* as a string and runs it with `eval`.  In the `jq` expression, `@sh` is used to provide proper quoting for the command name and its arguments.  The `jq` expression here expects an array of objects of the type shown in the question.